# Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Please i am trying to intergrate the facebook sdk for login, i have successfully implemented on my system using xampp with no issues, 
But when i migrated to server i started to have this error

Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing.

i checked online to see other peeps who were having this issue and most of them resoluted to turning on session at the start of their code which i have tried too but i still have the error

Please help

here is my code i dont know what else to do, my first time of encountering such

```
<?php
session_start();?>
<?php $title = 'Vote Now'; ?>

 <?php


error_reporting(0);
// Include FB config file && User class
require_once 'fbConfig.php';
require_once 'User.php';

if(isset($accessToken)){
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }else{
        // Put short-lived access token in session
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler helps to manage access tokens
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // Set default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // Redirect the user back to the same page if url has "code" parameter in query string
    if(isset($_GET['code'])){
        header('Location: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    }

    // Getting user facebook profile info
    try {
        $profileRequest = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture');
        $fbUserProfile = $profileRequest->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // Redirect user back to app login page
        header("Location: ./index.php");
        exit;
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // Initialize User class
    $user = new User();

    // Insert or update user data to the database
    $fbUserData = array(
        'oauth_provider'=> 'facebook',
        'oauth_uid'     => $fbUserProfile['id'],
        'first_name'    => $fbUserProfile['first_name'],
        'last_name'     => $fbUserProfile['last_name'],
        'email'         => $fbUserProfile['email'],
        'gender'        => $fbUserProfile['gender'],
        'locale'        => $fbUserProfile['locale'],
        'picture'       => $fbUserProfile['picture']['url'],
        'link'          => $fbUserProfile['link']
    );
    $userData = $user->checkUser($fbUserData);

    // Put user data into session
    $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;

    // Get logout url
    $logoutURL = $helper->getLogoutUrl($accessToken, $redirectURL.'logout.php');

    // Render facebook profile data
    if(!empty($userData)){
        $output  = '<h1>Facebook Profile Details </h1>';
        $output .= '<img src="'.$userData['picture'].'">';
       $output .= '<br/>Facebook ID : ' . $userData['oauth_uid'];
       $output .= '<br/>Name : ' . $userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name'];
      $output .= '<br/>Email : ' . $userData['email'];
       //$output .= '<br/>Gender : ' . $userData['gender'];
       //$output .= '<br/>Locale : ' . $userData['locale'];
       //$output .= '<br/>Logged in with : Facebook';
        //$output .= '<br/><a href="'.$userData['link'].'" target="_blank">Click to Visit Facebook Page</a>';
       // $output .= '<br/>Logout from <a href="logout.php">Facebook</a>'; 
    }else{
        $output = '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
    }

}else{
    // Get login url
    $loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions);

    // Render facebook login button
    //$output = '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url='.htmlspecialchars($loginURL).'" />';
    $output = '<div align="center"><a style="font-size:21px" href='.htmlspecialchars($loginURL).' />Login On Facebook To Vote</a></div>';
}
?>

<?php
if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}

// Include the autoloader provided in the SDK
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php';

// Include required libraries
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

/*
 * Configuration and setup Facebook SDK
 */
$appId          = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret      = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //Facebook App Secret
$redirectURL    = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //Callback URL
$fbPermissions  = array('email');  //Optional permissions

$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'app_id' => $appId,
    'app_secret' => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
));

// Get redirect login helper
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

// Try to get access token
try {
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    }else{
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

found out the solution there was a space within location url

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
            header('Location: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        } 





if(isset($_GET['code'])){
            header('Location:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        }
```